# How can I use Python to use repeating column value to separate rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with a repeating column value that I want to use to group records for insertion into a database. My approach is to use Pandas. Here is a representative dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['foo', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'foo', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3'],
    'b': ['bar', 'Zee', np.nan, 500, 'baz', 'Jay', 'Yes', 100]})
```

I want transpose it to this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': ['bar', 'baz'],
    'q1': ['Zee', 'Jay'],
    'q2': [numpy.nan, 'Yes'],
    'q3': [500, 100]})
```

by using the 'foo' value to separate rows or records. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establish column `group` by boolean selecting `foo` and using `.cumsum()` method. `.groupby` `group` and `a` and  `b` to list and `unstack`  `a`.

```
df2.assign(group=(df2.a=='foo').cumsum()).groupby(['group','a'])['b'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist())).unstack('a').reset_index(drop=True)

a  foo   q1   q2   q3
0  bar  Zee  NaN  500
1  baz  Jay  Yes  100
```

Comment: nice answer, but I do not think it is efficient ... you are creating a dataframe twice(first one with assign, the second in the apply function), plus more often than not, apply is not fast.

Answer (score 2):

We can do `cumsum` create the index then do `pivot`

```
df=df2.assign(index=df2.a.eq('foo').cumsum()).pivot('index','a','b')
df
a      foo   q1   q2   q3
index                    
1      bar  Zee  NaN  500
2      baz  Jay  Yes  100
```

Or we do `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
df=df2.assign(index=df2.groupby('a').cumcount()).pivot('index','a','b')
df
a      foo   q1   q2   q3
index                    
0      bar  Zee  NaN  500
1      baz  Jay  Yes  100
```

Comment: This seemed to work when I first tried it, but now when I run it I get: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"